# How can I return an array from view asp.net-mvc-3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have view model:

```
    Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        ...
        public IEnumerable<string> Emails { get; set; }
    }
```

I've post it in the view:

```
    ...
    @foreach (var Emails in Model.Emails)
    {
         @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Emails)
    }
    ...
```

How can I return to controller an array of this Emails?

When I return data from form to controller in this moment, property "Customer.Emails" equals null, but it should contain an array of e-mails.

Comment: I removed my answer as you requested, but I still think it was correct. I'll test it and update when I have time

Comment: Undelete your question I mark it as answer, it was my fault. I was simplify my view and model in question for easier understanding. In this case it's works! In my real program I will think how to apply it. Thanks for answer.

Comment: I think you need to look into Editor Templates for ASP.NET MVC3: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EditorFor()` call is incorrect.

You should remove the `foreach` and do

```
...
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Emails)
...
```

Comment: modelItem.Emails - it's an array. I ve try to put it, but it also cast array to string with all members in each edit.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Emails.Count; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Emails[i]);
}
```

otherwise it won't generate the correct id for model binding (as you are not giving the EditorFor any context).